# Datagridview menuitem - get data of datagridview row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, menuitem

I am using a Datagridview, and if I right click on a row in the Datagridview I am catching the Datagridview MouseClick handler. Inside this handler I create a menuItem, if I click one entry in this menuItem I want to execute some code, and this code should get some data from the row I have selected in the Datagridview. How can I do this?

I am using this kind of code to create menuItem entrys:

`Dim firefox As New MenuItem("Firefox", AddressOf contextMenu_ItemClicked)
 firefox.Tag = "firefox"`

Another question, do I need to add this tag, or am I also able to read out the name of the menuitem in the contextMenu_ItemClicked function?

Thanks!

Comment: How about getting the data first so you have it and then when you click on a menu item to perform some logic you have the data you need? Please update the post with what you have tried and where you are stuck at.

Comment: First things first, you should not be using the `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem` classes, which became obsolete in 2005. You should be using the `ContextMenuStrip` and `ToolStripMenuItem` classes. Either way though, the item in the menu will have a `Tag` property and you can put the required data there, as @Çöđěxěŕ suggests.